# Next JS + Custom Node Lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a nextJS with a node server to zeit Now.

Here is my the script, I have tried deploying the code below but the app crashes anytime I hit the '/api/subscribe' route because of the axios request. The error gotten is a `502 NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_FUNCTION`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { NowRequest, NowResponse } from '@now/node'

export default function(req: NowRequest, res: NowResponse) {
  const { email } = req.body

  const MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
  const MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID = process.env.MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID
  const MAILCHIMP_INSTANCE = process.env.MAILCHIMP_INSTANCE

  const subscriber = {
    email_address: email,
    status: 'subscribed'
  }

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://${MAILCHIMP_INSTANCE}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID}/members/`,
    data: subscriber,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `apikey ${MAILCHIMP_API_KEY}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const { status } = data
      res.status(200).send({ success: status })
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
      const { data } = response
      const { status, detail } = data
      res.status(status).send({ error: detail })
    })
}
```

Comment: custom server approach is generally bad practice these days, instead create a folder called "api" in your pages directory, each default export in this folder becomes a endpoint relative to its path in "api"; to be deployed as a serverless lamda

Comment: Hello @ShanonJackson, I created an api folder already, but still having issues with axios when deployed. I have updated the code above.